# Entity Framework code

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm creating a small vb.net application. I'm just trying entity framework. When i use methods such as

```
          ctx.DeleteObject(whatever)
```

How do you see the actual code behind and how it deletes from the database? is it possible to see the code somewhere how it works behind the scenes?

Comment: Did you mean the actual implementation or the generated SQL code?

Comment: Which EF version are you working with? This seems to be the deprecated ObjectContext API. Not the best place to start trying.

Comment: the sql code behind the scenes

Answer (score 0):

Most of the .net code is not open source esp entity frame work earlier version but their version 7 beta is released under github you can look and see what the function does their.

This best describes what happenes

When you call a delete like the following

```
var context = new SalesOrderManagementEntities();
    IQueryable CustomerQuery =
               (from p in context.Customer
                where p.Name == "Vam"
                select p);
    Customer mySelectedCustomer =CustomerQuery.First();
    context.DeleteObject(mySelectedCustomer);
    context.SaveChanges();
```

When we call the DeleteObject() method, the ObjectContext marks the objects' state to deleted but not delete the object.

The delete only happens when we call SaveChanges so its like a soft delete in memory. Until we call Save Changes

Comment: Yes, i realize thats the code to delete. but just wondering how it actually deletes from the database behind the scenes. like the actual sql code... i guess its not open source